# background-color of img element containing transparent SVG ins't displayed in iOS browser

Tags: html, ios, css, svg

I'm having trouble getting the `background-color` CSS property of an SVG image element to be honored by iOS browser. I'm using a 3rd-gen iPad (Model MD366LL/A, iOS 6.1.3) for testing.
I've tried several SVG images with transparent backgrounds, and the browser does not respect the background color set on the `img` element. The background color of an ancestor element ends up being displayed instead.
The same issue does not occur when using transparent PNGs. Also, other browsers I've tested honor the background color set on the `img` element (Android Browser, Opera, Firefox, Dolphin Browser and Chrome on Android 4.4; Firefox and Opera on Ubuntu 13.10 x64). I don't have access to an iPhone at the moment.

Some example code (substitute an URI to a transparent SVG image in the `img` element's `src` attribute):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Test</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            html, body {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                position: relative;
            }

            .container {
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: #222222;
            }

            .image {
                width: 20%;
                background-color: #888888;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="image.svg" class="image">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is this a bug in the rendering of the image element, or am I missing something? If it is a bug, is there a workaround that doesn't require adding additional markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't test against your question thoroughly, but if this is problem, you can try the following by wrapping the image instead.

HTML

```
<div class="images">
    <img src="image.svg"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.images {
    background: #333;
}

.images img {
    width: 20%;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Here's a more modular approach for laying out a list of images.

You could do the following:

HTML

```
<div class="image-list">

    <div class="image-list__item">
        <img src="image.svg"/>
    </div>

    <div class="image-list__item">
        <img src="image.svg"/>
    </div>

    <div class="image-list__item">
        <img src="image.svg"/>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image-list {
    background: #333;
    padding: 12px;
}

.image-list .image-list__item {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    padding: 12px;
}

.image-list .image-list__item img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.clearfix {
    clear:both;
}
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/JMDUK/pen/njoHD) or [DEMO](http://codepen.io/JMDUK/pen/FmDzj) using list items (a more semantic approach).

Comment: I'll see if I can make this work. Is there a way to wrap the image and have it alongside other inline elements?

Comment: @Chase -- See updated answer dude. Hope this helps! See the demo for a better insight.

Comment: I am able to set the background-color of a transparent SVG in mobile Safari without changing all the other images' backgrounds. Thanks